# is this question about ipv6 offtopic?

Tags: discussion

my question [do domains work with ipv6 only nowadays? how much dedicated ipv6 costs?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127518/is-there-a-ipv6-only-example-domain) is closed. then, i have written a comment there:

> "This question does not appear to be about running a website." - how
>   it is no about that? ipv4s are not given for free. i think, maybe
>   ipv6s are free? but, i also should check it out, is it going to work.
>   maintaining ip addresses is like maintaining domains, is not it job of
>   webmasters? ok, somebody may be not trusting webmasters and
>   configuring his domains, but some clients may rely on webmasters. and
>   ips are not as expensive as domains at all, and are more frequently
>   changed, and it should be done by webmasters. – qdinar 22 hours ago

and i doubt that anybody have seen that comment. so i write here to bring attention.

utc+3 feb2 10:32: i have changed the question.

Answer (score 2):

The primary way to bring attention to your closed question is to edit it.  When you edit your closed question, it automatically enters the re-enter queue where it will be looked at.

Another way to bring attention to your closed question would be to flag it for moderator attention.  A moderator would be happy to take another look at your question after you have changed it, or commented.

Posting here in meta is OK, but it would get pretty cluttered if everybody did that for every closed question.

Your question as originally written was off topic for two reasons.  You asked for an example site that is IPV6 only.

1. That isn't about your own website.  We answer questions you have about your own website, not about examples of other people's websites.
2. That is asking for an external resource.  Questions that ask for recommendations tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

When you edited your question, you have solved those two issues, however, your question was "too broad" because you asking multiple questions in a single post.

Now that you have edited your question a third time, it looks OK to me, and I re-opened it.